# Organizing methods for better accessing them

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a general library which would have all methods for managing data on our database.

This library will have a lot of methods so I would like to make it more organized. I would like it to be used with the following syntax.

```
db.setData().insertNewAccount(username, password);

db.modifyData().deleteAccount(username, password);

db.getData().getAccount();
```

How would I make it work like that if I type setData for example methods related to setData would show up.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what tags are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do it that way, then you could do something like this (pseudo code):

```
class DataRepository
{
    public SetDataHelper setData()
    { return new SetDataHelper(); }

    public ModifyDataHelper modifyData()
    { return new ModifyDataHelper(); }

    public GetDataHelper getData()
    { return new GetDataHelper(); }
}

class SetDataHelper
{
    public void insertNewAccount(username, password) { ... }
}

class ModifyDataHelper
{
    public void deleteAccount(username, password) { ... }
}

class GetDataHelper
{
    public Account getAccount() { ... }
}
```

And then you could do it your way, more fluently:

```
var db = new DataRepository();

db.setData().insertNewAccount(username, password);

db.modifyData().deleteAccount(username, password);

db.getData().getAccount();
```

Comment: thanks for this, but when you said "If I really want to do it this way" do you mean there are better and more standard way of organizing code? this class will have about 60 methods and if I press dot after the object name it will be hard to look though them.

Comment: I had Jon Skeet's answer in mind when I wrote that line =) I would also have done one repository for each business class, rather than a class for each (CRUD) action. But this works to =)

Comment: Should I make "class SetDataHelper" public? When I try to build it without public I get the following compile error saying its less accessible.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're approaching this the wrong way - typically you'd have something like an `AccountRepository` class with all the members relating to accounts; then you'd have (say) an `ArticleRepository` class with all the members relating to articles.

In other words, organize by the *kind of data you're dealing with* rather than whether you're trying to fetch, update, insert etc.

Then you can use dependency injection so that each business class will be given just the repositories it uses.

Answer (score 0):

You can create different interfaces, with different functionality, and your class can implement all of them. And then, your `setData()` can return the class itself, cast to the correcponding interface. E.g:

```
interface SetData {
  int insertNewAccount(A, B);
}

interface ModifyData {
  int deleteAccount(A, B);
}

interface GetData {
  int getAccount(A, B);
}

class DBHandler : SetData, ModifyData , GetData {
  //
  // Implement the interfaces...
  //

  // Returns the interfaces
  SetData setData(){ return (SetData)this; }
  ModifyData modifyData (){ return (ModifyData )this; }
  GetData getData (){ return (GetData )this; }
}
```

It does what you want, of course use the access modifiers accordingly your project. And this solution doesn't stop you from reaching the implemented interface functions directly, that would need another class, or something to proxy all call toward the DB class.