# Creating an organized Java library

Tags: java, class, jar

I want to create a library(Jar file) in Java which would contain all my methods for the database we use. There are about 60 methods in there so I would like to make it more organized. I would like to call the methods like the example provided below.

```
db.accounts.add(username, password); or db.accounts().add(username, password);
db.names.delete(name); or db.names().delete(name);
```

What is the best way of doing this in Java?

Comment: Organized how? I don't understand the question.

Comment: Pretty much I want to have the methods related to managing accounts in a way that when I type db.accounts I get methods related to managing methods.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing in this post but in Java

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361877/organizing-methods-for-better-accessing-them/10361968#comment13361067_10361968

Comment: @Arya then do the exact same thing. The code in that answer is valid as Java code, except for that 'var'.

Comment: @DaveNewton: I think he talking about Design Pattern, to make it more like DAO structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could save yourself a lot of trouble and write a generic DAO:

```
package persistence;

public interface GenericDao<K, V> {
    V find(K id);
    List<V> find();
    K save(V value);
    void update(V value);
    void delete(V value);
}
```

I'd forget about writing your own persistence classes and use a proven solution, like Spring JDBC template.

This problem has been solved many times, many ways.  What do you hope to do to improve upon what exists?  How will you justify the added expense of developing, testing, and maintaining this functionality?

Comment: I asked the same question but it was related to c# and it was simple to implement. I think you misunderstood my question. Here is the link to the c# question. I'm pretty much asking the same thing but for Java

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361877/organizing-methods-for-better-accessing-them/10361968#comment13361067_10361968

Comment: No, I didn't.  My answer is unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Here some snapshot of my custom library for connect to database:

[image]

**PostgreConnection.java**

```
public class PostgreConnection {

private static Connection conn;

public Connection makeConnection(String url, String db, String username, String password) {
    if (conn == null) {
        try {
            Class.forName(Constants.POSTGRES_DRIVER);

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Constants.POSTGRES_URL + url + "/" + db, username, password);
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PostgreConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    return conn;
}
```

}

**Constants.java**

```
public class Constants {

    public static String POSTGRES_URL = "jdbc:postgresql://";
    public static String POSTGRES_DRIVER = "org.postgresql.Driver";
}
```

In `org.ert.model` you can store all the `Model` that you need based on the tables of your database.

**NotifyCharts.java**

```
public class NotifyCharts {

private Integer Id;
private String revName;
private Date importDate;
private Integer pages;
private Boolean status;

public Integer getId() {
    return Id;
}

public void setId(Integer Id) {
    this.Id = Id;
}

public Date getImportDate() {
    return importDate;
}

public void setImportDate(Date importDate) {
    this.importDate = importDate;
}

public Integer getPages() {
    return pages;
}

public void setPages(Integer pages) {
    this.pages = pages;
}

public String getRevName() {
    return revName;
}

public void setRevName(String revName) {
    this.revName = revName;
}

public Boolean isStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(Boolean status) {
    this.status = status;
}
}
```

`SQLQuery` is an `abstract class` for some basic method such as `insert, update, delete, etc`.

**SQLQuery.java**

```
public abstract class SQLQuery<T> {
    protected void makeStatement(String url, String db, String username, String password) {
    PostgreConnection connect = new PostgreConnection();
    Connection con = connect.makeConnection(url, db, username, password);

    try {
        state = (Statement) con.createStatement();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SQLQuery.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public String arrayBuilder(Object[] obj, boolean val) {
    StringBuilder arr = new StringBuilder();

    arr.append("(");
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        if (i < obj.length - 1) {
            if (val) {
                arr.append("'");
            }
            arr.append(obj[i]);

            if (val) {
                arr.append("'");
            }

            arr.append(", ");
        } else {
            if (val) {
                arr.append("'");
            }
            arr.append(obj[i]);
            if (val) {
                arr.append("'");
            }
        }
    }
    arr.append(")");

    return arr.toString();
}

public int insertRecord() throws SQLException {
    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();

    query.append("INSERT INTO ").append(tableName).append(arrayBuilder(columns, false)).append(" VALUES ").append(arrayBuilder(values, true));

    return state.executeUpdate(query.toString());
}

public ResultSet getAll() throws SQLException {
    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();

    query.append("SELECT * FROM ").append(tableName);
    rSet = state.executeQuery(query.toString());

    return rSet;
}

public abstract void setColsAndVals(T t);
}
```

`NotifyChartsSQL.java` is implementation of the `abstract class`, `org.ert.sql.impl` is `package` to store all your implementation that you need.

**NotifyChartsSQL.java**

```
public class NotifyChartsSQL extends SQLQuery<NotifyCharts> {

public NotifyChartsSQL(String url, String db, String username, String password, NotifyCharts notify) {
    makeStatement(url, db, username, password);
    setColsAndVals(notify);
}

@Override
public final void setColsAndVals(NotifyCharts notify) {
    Map<String, Object> objects = new HashMap<>();
    String[] columns;
    Object[] values;

    if(notify.getId() != null)
        objects.put("id", notify.getId());
    if(notify.getRevName() != null)
        objects.put("rev_name", notify.getRevName());
    if(notify.getImportDate() != null)
        objects.put("import_date", notify.getImportDate());
    if(notify.getPages() != null)
        objects.put("pages", notify.getPages());

    objects.put("status", notify.isStatus());

    columns = Arrays.copyOf(objects.keySet().toArray(), objects.size(), String[].class);
    values = objects.values().toArray();

    setColumns(columns);
    setValues(values);
    setTableName("notify_charts");
}

}
```

And last is the `test` package that test your custom library to make sure that everything is ok.

**TestMain.java**

```
public class TestMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    NotifyCharts notify = new NotifyCharts();
    try {

        notify.setRevName("Test456");
        notify.setImportDate(new Date());
        notify.setPages(10);
        notify.setStatus(false);

        NotifyChartsSQL notCharts = new NotifyChartsSQL("localhost:5432", "charts", "username", "password", notify);


        int status = notCharts.insertRecord();

        if (status == 1) {
            System.out.println("Success Insert");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed Insert");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TestMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

}

I suggest if you want to make this custom library if you using manual `JDBC` and not using `ORM` such as `Hibernate`. Because in Hibernate is already provide all the methods that you need except do you want to add some special method you can do like duffymo said before. This idea of custom library is come from the `DAO` and the `Hibernate` structure.

Thanks for read it, and please learn some [Design Pattern in Java](http://www.javacamp.org/designPattern/) if you want to make some custom library that more organized.