# How to print Two-Dimensional Array like table

Tags: java, arrays, text, format

I'm having a problem with two dimensional array. I'm having a display like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 . . . etc
```

What basically I want is to display to display it as:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6     7  
8 9 10 11 12 13 14  
15 16 17 18 19 20  
21 22 23 24 ... etc
```

Here is my code:

```
    int twoDm[][]= new int[7][5];
    int i,j,k=1;

        for(i=0;i<7;i++){
            for(j=0;j<5;j++) {
             twoDm[i][j]=k;
                k++;}
        }

        for(i=0;i<7;i++){
            for(j=0;j<5;j++) {
                System.out.print(twoDm[i][j]+" ");
                System.out.print("");}
        }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
public class FormattedTablePrint {

    public static void printRow(int[] row) {
        for (int i : row) {
            System.out.print(i);
            System.out.print("\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int twoDm[][]= new int[7][5];
        int i,j,k=1;

        for(i=0;i<7;i++) {
            for(j=0;j<5;j++) {
                twoDm[i][j]=k;
                k++;
            }
        }

        for(int[] row : twoDm) {
            printRow(row);
        }
    }
}
```

### Output

```
1   2   3   4   5   
6   7   8   9   10  
11  12  13  14  15  
16  17  18  19  20  
21  22  23  24  25  
26  27  28  29  30  
31  32  33  34  35
```

Of course, you might swap the 7 & 5 as mentioned in other answers, to get 7 per row.

Comment: What happens if the ith jth element has many more digits than ith +-1 and jth element?

Comment: Is there a way to use `printf` so I can print a table of strings with variable sizes and still have the rows/columns aligned? (e.g. the array might be `{{"bat","stegosaurus","turtle"}, {"horse", "armadillo", "cow"}}`)

Answer (score 28):

If you don't mind the commas and the brackets you can simply use:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(twoDm).replace("], ", "]\n"));
```

Comment: Nice and simple, requiring no extra dependencies. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

You need to print a new line after each row...  `System.out.print("\n")`, or use `println`, etc.  As it stands you are just printing nothing - `System.out.print("")`, replace `print` with `println` or `""` with `"\n"`.

Comment: I've just replaced it and now i have and output like: 1 2 3 5 6 7 8 etc but its only vertical. what i want is like a table. anyway, thanks for the reply.

Comment: He said to put the `println()` after every ROW, not after every print you do.  In other words, after executing the second `for()` loop but before allowing the first to loop around.

Comment: Make sure your println is in the correct scope.  Your first print statement concatenates everything on the same line, so you need to make sure your line break happens outside the scope of the "j" for loop.

Comment: By the way. How should i make it like print 1-7 first then 8-14 etc. Im really having a hard time understanding this.

Comment: @kix: Have you tried my **[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12845250/500725)**.

Answer (score 11):

You could write a method to print a 2d array like this:

```
//Displays a 2d array in the console, one line per row.
static void printMatrix(int[][] grid) {
    for(int r=0; r<grid.length; r++) {
       for(int c=0; c<grid[r].length; c++)
           System.out.print(grid[r][c] + " ");
       System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is maybe what i need. I'll try this and post here later the output. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A part from **@djechlin** answer, you should change the rows and columns. Since you are taken as 7 rows and 5 columns, but actually you want is 7 columns and 5 rows.

Do this way:-

```
int twoDm[][]= new int[5][7];

for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    for(j=0;j<7;j++) {
        System.out.print(twoDm[i][j]+" ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: yes man. and now im having exception a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: @kix: Updated my answer with array declaration as per your expectation. `int twoDm[][]= new int[5][7];`

Comment: Trolls must be at work.. I see nothing wrong with your answer.

Comment: @Siva Charan - it's working now but still displaying in 1 one row. what i want is displaying it in 5 rows without using grid. thanks!

Comment: @sircapsalot - nope. ive just declared the array as [7][5]. hehe im just a beginner.

Comment: @kix: It will work. Just check whether last statement is used as this `System.out.println("");`

Comment: @Siva charan - i found a solution to my statement ive added and if statement `if (twoDm[i][j]%7==1)`.

Answer (score 3):

I'll post a solution with a bit more elaboration, in addition to code, as the initial mistake and the subsequent ones that have been demonstrated in comments are common errors in this sort of string concatenation problem.

From the initial question, as has been adequately explained by @djechlin, we see that there is the need to print a new line after each line of your table has been completed.  So, we need this statement:

```
System.out.println();
```

However, printing that immediately after the first print statement gives erroneous results.  What gives?

```
1 
2 
...
n
```

This is a problem of scope.  Notice that there are two loops for a reason -- one loop handles rows, while the other handles columns.  Your inner loop, the "j" loop, iterates through each array element "j" for a given "i."  Therefore, at the end of the j loop, you should have a single row. You can think of each iterate of this "j" loop as building the "columns" of your table.  Since the inner loop builds our columns, we don't want to print our line there -- it would make a new line for each element!

Once you are out of the j loop, you need to terminate that row before moving on to the next "i" iterate.  This is the correct place to handle a new line, because it is the "scope" of your table's rows, instead of your table's columns.

```
for(i=0;i<7;i++){
    for(j=0;j<5;j++) {
        System.out.print(twoDm[i][j]+" ");  
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

And you can see that this new line will hold true, even if you change the dimensions of your table by changing the end values of your "i" and "j" loops.

Comment: is this code also correct `for(i=0;i<5;i++){  
            for(j=0;j<7;j++){  
                if (twoDm[i][j]%7==1)
                System.out.print("\n");
                System.out.print(twoDm[i][j]+"   ");`

Comment: @Kix Not quite.  It's a simple fix, though -- just move the second print statement inside of the inner loop.  You can't call individual cells outside of the inner for loop, because you'll get an out of bounds exception.  It'll compile after you correct that, but it will be messy because you'll have a blank line before your output.  Review what your loops should be doing, and rearrange your lines to get your desired formatting.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the records, Java 8 provides a better alternative.

```
int[][] table = new int[][]{{2,4,5},{6,34,7},{23,57,2}};

System.out.println(Stream.of(table)
    .map(rowParts -> Stream.of(rowParts
    .map(element -> ((Integer)element).toString())
        .collect(Collectors.joining("\t")))
    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
```

Answer (score 3):

More **efficient and easy way** to print the 2D array in a formatted way:

Try this:

```
public static void print(int[][] puzzle) {
        for (int[] row : puzzle) {
            for (int elem : row) {
                System.out.printf("%4d", elem);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

**Sample Output:**

```
   0   1   2   3
   4   5   6   7
   8   9  10  11
  12  13  14  15
```

Answer (score 1):

You can creat a method that prints the matrix as a table :

Note: That does not work well on matrices with numbers with many digits and
       non-square matrices.

```
    public static void printMatrix(int size,int row,int[][] matrix){

            for(int i = 0;i <  7 * size ;i++){ 
                  System.out.print("-");    
            }
                 System.out.println("-");

            for(int i = 1;i <= matrix[row].length;i++){
               System.out.printf("| %4d ",matrix[row][i - 1]);
             }
               System.out.println("|");


                 if(row == size -  1){

             // when we reach the last row,
             // print bottom line "---------"

                    for(int i = 0;i <  7 * size ;i++){ 
                          System.out.print("-");
                     }
                          System.out.println("-");

                  }
   }

  public static void main(String[] args){

     int[][] matrix = {

              {1,2,3,4},
              {5,6,7,8},
              {9,10,11,12},
              {13,14,15,16}


      };

       // print the elements of each row:

     int rowsLength = matrix.length;

          for(int k = 0; k < rowsLength; k++){

              printMatrix(rowsLength,k,matrix);
          }


  }
```

Output :

```
---------------------
|  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |
---------------------
|  5 |  6 |  7 |  8 |
---------------------
|  9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
---------------------
| 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 |
---------------------
```

I created this method while practicing loops and arrays, I'd rather use:

`System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix).replace("], ", "]\n")));`

Answer (score 1):

Iliya,

Sorry for that.

you code is work. but its had some problem with Array row and columns

here i correct your code this work correctly, you can try this ..

```
public static void printMatrix(int size, int row, int[][] matrix) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 7 * matrix[row].length; i++) {
        System.out.print("-");
    }
    System.out.println("-");

    for (int i = 1; i <= matrix[row].length; i++) {
        System.out.printf("| %4d ", matrix[row][i - 1]);
    }
    System.out.println("|");

    if (row == size - 1) {

        // when we reach the last row,
        // print bottom line "---------"

        for (int i = 0; i < 7 * matrix[row].length; i++) {
            System.out.print("-");
        }
        System.out.println("-");

    }
}

public static void length(int[][] matrix) {

    int rowsLength = matrix.length;

    for (int k = 0; k < rowsLength; k++) {

        printMatrix(rowsLength, k, matrix);

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] matrix = { { 1, 2, 5 }, { 3, 4, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 }

    };

    length(matrix);

}
```

and out put look like

```
----------------------
|    1 |    2 |    5 |
----------------------
|    3 |    4 |    6 |
----------------------
|    7 |    8 |    9 |
----------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Declared a 7 by 5 array which is similar to yours, with some dummy data. Below should do.

```
    int[][] array = {{21, 12, 32, 14, 52}, {43, 43, 55, 66, 72}, {57, 64, 52, 57, 88},{52, 33, 54, 37, 82},{55, 62, 35, 17, 28},{55, 66, 58, 72, 28}}; 
    
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println(); // the trick is here, print a new line after iterating first row.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class class1 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[][] a={{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
        
        for (int i = 0; i< a.length; i++){
            System.out.print("Row" + (i + 1) + ": ");
            for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++){
                System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**result:**

```
Row1: 1 2 3                                                                                          
Row2: 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just use for each**

```
int[][] matrix = // this is your 2d array.
for (int[] x: matrix) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This might be late however this method does what you ask in a perfect manner, it even shows the elements in ' table - like ' style, which is brilliant for beginners to really understand how an Multidimensional Array looks.

```
public static void display(int x[][])   // So we allow the method to take as input Multidimensional arrays
    {
        //Here we use 2 loops, the first one is for the rows and the second one inside of the rows is for the columns
        for(int rreshti = 0; rreshti < x.length; rreshti++)     // Loop for the rows
        {
            for(int kolona = 0; kolona < x[rreshti].length;kolona++)        // Loop for the columns
            {
                System.out.print(x[rreshti][kolona] + "\t");            // the \t simply spaces out the elements for a clear view   
            }
            System.out.println();   // And this empty outputprint, simply makes sure each row (the groups we wrote in the beggining in seperate {}), is written in a new line, to make it much clear and give it a table-like look 
        }
    }
```

After you complete creating this method, you simply put this into your main method:

```
display(*arrayName*); // So we call the method by its name, which can be anything, does not matter, and give that method an input (the Array's name)
```

NOTE. Since we made the method so that it requires Multidimensional Array as a input it wont work for 1 dimensional arrays (which would make no sense anyways)

Source: [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hbot9MQVHOM)

PS. It might be confusing a little bit since I used my language to name the elements / variables, however CBA to translate them, sorry.

Answer (score -2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] matrix = { 
                       { 1, 2, 5 }, 
                       { 3, 4, 6 },
                       { 7, 8, 9 } 
                     };

    System.out.println(" ** Matrix ** ");

    for (int rows = 0; rows < 3; rows++) {
        System.out.println("\n");
        for (int columns = 0; columns < matrix[rows].length; columns++) {
            System.out.print(matrix[rows][columns] + "\t");
        }
    }
}
```

This works,add a new line in for loop of the row. When the first row will be done printing the code will jump in new line.

Comment: This is essentially what Andrew Thompson's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12845811/369450) already does.

Answer (score -2):

```
For traversing through a 2D array, I think the following for loop can be used.

        for(int a[]: twoDm)
        {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
        }
if you don't want the commas you can string replace
if you want this to be performant you should loop through a[] and then print it.
```

Comment: Please try to provide context with your answer.  A standalone answer may solve a problem in this specific scenario, but an explanation may solve many future problems.  Try to include what you think is causing the issue and why your answer will solve it.

Answer (score -3):

ALL OF YOU PLEASE LOOT AT IT I Am amazed it need little IQ 
just get length by arr[0].length and problem solved

```
   for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < test[0].length; j++) {

        System.out.print(test[i][j]);
    }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: This answer is really redundant. This is basically a worse version of the existing answers because it doesn't add spacing between the numbers within each row.