# Building 9x9 with toString

Tags: java

I have a list of 81 numeric values. I'm trying to write a toString method so it prints my values in a `9x9` format. Right now, all I'm getting is printed values until it reaches the end of the line, and then starting on a new line.
This is my body of code.

```
public class Board{
  public static final int Size = 9;
  private Cell[][] arr = new Cell[Board.Size][Board.Size];

  public Board(){
    this.arr = new Cell[Board.Size][Board.Size];
    for (int i=0; i<Board.Size; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j<Board.Size; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = new Cell(i, j, 0);
         
      }  
    }
  }

  public String toString(){
    String myBoard = new String();
    myBoard = "[";
    for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
      for(int j=0; j<arr[i].length; j++){
        myBoard += " " + arr[i][j].getValue();
      }
    }
    myBoard += "]";
    myBoard += "\n";
    return myBoard;
  }
```

And this is my current output:

[image: 1]

This looks like a simple problem yet I haven't figured it out in 30 minutes, which is why I'm asking.

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12845208/how-to-print-two-dimensional-array-like-table

Comment: You should print a `"\n"` after the inner loop

Comment: You should be printing a newline at the end of each row

Comment: You should add `myBoard += "\n";` after second for-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work and print it out like this:

[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

```
String myBoard = "";
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  myBoard += "[";
  for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){ 
    myBoard += " " + arr[i][j].getValue();
  }
  myBoard += "]";
  myBoard += "\n";
}
```