# The best way to print a Java 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, printing, 2d

I was wondering what the best way of printing a 2D array in Java was?

I was just wondering if this code is good practice or not?
Also any other mistakes I made in this code if you find any.

```
int rows = 5;
int columns = 3;

int[][] array = new int[rows][columns];

for (int i = 0; i<rows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j<columns; j++)
        array[i][j] = 0;

for (int i = 0; i<rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j<columns; j++) {
        System.out.print(array[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Best -- by what definition?

Comment: Your for loops would be safer if they used the actual array lengths.

Comment: Some examples in the following [SO question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383070/pretty-print-2d-array-in-java

Answer (score 250):

You can print in simple way.

Use below to print 2D array

```
int[][] array = new int[rows][columns];
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
```

Use below to print 1D array

```
int[] array = new int[size];
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Comment: The 2D version prints everything on a single line, which is not ok :(

Comment: @DangManhTroung then write a for loop with a print line.

Comment: I know this is a little later, but this prints everything out on separate lines. [I took this from this so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12845208/how-to-print-two-dimensional-array-like-table#17423410)  `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(twoDm).replace("], ", "]\n"));`

Answer (score 34):

I would prefer generally `foreach` when I don't need making arithmetic operations with their indices.

```
for (int[] x : array)
{
   for (int y : x)
   {
        System.out.print(y + " ");
   }
   System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Good compromise with readability and without calling the Collections API.

Comment: This one is the best answer. The code prints everything out neatly in a table

Comment: I had to use change the type to `List<Integer>` instead of int[]. It looks similar but one needs to use the type of an ArrayList of Integers to this `for (List<Integer> a : arr)` for the first line of code.

Comment: @ShivaShankar why don't you try to use var keyword?

Answer (score 32):

Simple and clean way to print a 2D array.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array).replace("], ", "]\n").replace("[[", "[").replace("]]", "]"));
```

Comment: That's not clean.

Comment: I think it's clean.

Comment: Less surface area for bugs.

Answer (score 12):

There is nothing wrong with what you have. Double-nested for loops should be easily digested by anyone reading your code.

That said, the following formulation is denser and more idiomatic java. I'd suggest poking around some of the static utility classes like [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) and [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) sooner than later. Tons of boilerplate can be shaved off by their efficient use.

```
for (int[] row : array)
{
    Arrays.fill(row, 0);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
}
```

Comment: This solution will print your array with (0,0) at the top left corner (which is the convention for most things in CS, such as GUI placement or Pixel location in an image).  In many non-cs scenarios you would want (0,0) to be in the lower left corner, though, in which case a foreach loop will not work.

Answer (score 10):

Two-liner with new line:

```
for(int[] x: matrix)
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
```

One liner without new line:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix));
```

Comment: best answer,  for printing multidimensional array

Answer (score 6):

That's the best I guess:

```
   for (int[] row : matrix){
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
   }
```

Answer (score 5):

From [Oracle Offical Java 8 Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString-java.lang.Object:A-):

`public static String deepToString(Object[] a)`

> Returns a string representation of the "deep contents" of the
>   specified array. If the array contains other arrays as elements, the
>   string representation contains their contents and so on. This method
>   is designed for converting multidimensional arrays to strings.

Answer (score 4):

```
|1 2 3|
|4 5 6|
```

Use the code below to print the values.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString());
```

Output will look like this (the whole matrix in one line):

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

Answer (score 3):

With Java 8 using Streams and ForEach:

```
    Arrays.stream(array).forEach((i) -> {
        Arrays.stream(i).forEach((j) -> System.out.print(j + " "));
        System.out.println();
    });
```

The first `forEach` acts as outer loop while the next as inner loop

Answer (score 2):

@Ashika's answer works fantastically if you want (0,0) to be represented in the top, left corner, per standard matrix convention.  If however you would prefer to put (0,0) in the lower left hand corner, in the style of the standard coordinate system, you could use this:

```
LinkedList<String> printList = new LinkedList<String>();
for (char[] row: array) {
    printList.addFirst(Arrays.toString(row));;
}
while (!printList.isEmpty())
    System.out.println(printList.removeFirst());
```

This used LIFO (Last In First Out) to reverse the order at print time.

Comment: A normal mathematical convention is to have element (0,0) (or rather (1,1)) in the top left corner when we talk about matrices, which arrays represent. I guess you wanted to allude to the coordinate system, but the way you phrased it - mixes up different concepts and is simply untrue.

Comment: Hi @jojo ... I wrote this answer in 2016, 1 year into a BS in math.  A BS and part of a PhD later, I agree with you.  I'll edit the answer accordingly.  :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array)
                         .replace("],","\n").replace(",","\t| ")
                         .replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", " "));
```

You can remove unwanted brackets with `.replace()`, after `.deepToString` if you like. 
That will look like:

```
 1  |  2  |  3
 4  |  5  |  6
 7  |  8  |  9
 10 |  11 |  12
 13 |  15 |  15
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
for (char[] temp : box) {
    System.err.println(Arrays.toString(temp).replaceAll(",", " ").replaceAll("\\[|\\]", ""));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapting from https://stackoverflow.com/a/49428678/1527469 (to add indexes):

```
System.out.print(" ");
for (int row = 0; row < array[0].length; row++) {
    System.out.print("\t" + row );
}
System.out.println();
for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++) {
        if (col < 1) {
            System.out.print(row);
            System.out.print("\t" + array[row][col]);
        } else {

            System.out.print("\t" + array[row][col]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MultidimensionalArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // create a 2d array
        int[][] a = {
                {1, -2, 3},
                {-4, -5, 6, 9},
                {7},
        };

        // first for...each loop access the individual array
        // inside the 2d array
        for (int[] innerArray: a) {
            // second for...each loop access each element inside the row
            for(int data: innerArray) {
                System.out.println(data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can do it like this for 2D array