# JAVA displaying an array as matrix and random numbers are equal to the minimum

Tags: java, arrays

I have to write a `JAVA` program where a user set the number of columns and rows of a `2d` array. Then he should choose a minimum and a maximum. After that, the array is filled randomly.

I writed this code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class array2d
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int rows, col, min, max;

        Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter number of rows and columns:");
        rows = scan1.nextInt();
        col = scan1.nextInt();
        int[][] a = new int[rows][col];
        System.out.println("Enter min and max:");
        min = scan1.nextInt();
        max = scan1.nextInt();

        for(int i = 0; i<rows; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<col; j++)
            {
                a[i][j] = min - (int)Math.random()*(max-min+1);
            }
        }

        //Display on the screen
        for(int i = 0; i<rows; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<col; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(a[i][j]+ " ");
            }
        }
        ...
     }
}
```

Then we should run a program to see if the first number of each row is a divisor of all the row:

```
for(int i = 0; i<rows; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<col; j++)
            {
                if(a[i][0]%a[i][j]==0)
                {
                    System.out.println(a[i][j]);
                }
                else
                    System.out.println("None");
            }
        }
```

That's working properly, but the generated array on my computer is displayed like that (CMD output):

[image]

And as you see in the picture, all randomly filled random are equal to the minimum specified.

So how can I display this array as like matrix and why the random numbers are showing like this.

Comment: Please don't post text as a screenshot. Post text as text.

Comment: it is a cmd output sir

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648240/java-best-way-to-print-2d-array

Comment: When displaying your output, you can put a `System.out.println();` after the inner `for-loop`. That should format the output into a nice matrix like intended.

Comment: Also: Why are there 10 output-values (those 10 tens)? If you create a 3x3 matrix, you should have only 9 values.

Comment: Ok I don't know that is a new problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Math#random` return a number between `0.0-1.0`, but less then `1.0`. This does in fact make your calculation look like the following `min-0`, since you are parsing it as `int`. Due to this you are allways saying `0*(max-min+1)`.

In order to achive what you want you need to add braces and add to min.

For your representation problem, add a `System.out.println` after you finished the inner loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i<rows; i++)  {
   for(int j = 0; j<col; j++)  {
       a[i][j] = min + (int)(Math.random()*(max-min+1)); // You need brackets and add it to min
   }
}
//Display on the screen
for(int i = 0; i<rows; i++) {
   for(int j = 0; j<col; j++){
       System.out.print(a[i][j]+ " ");
   }
   System.out.println(); // You need a linebreak
}
```

Answer (score 3):

All slots of your array get filled wit the 10 value in your example, `min` in general :

```
a[i][j] = min - (int)Math.random()*(max-min+1);
```

yields

```
a[i][j] = 10 - (int)Math.random()*(10);
```

`Math.random()` returns a  double greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0 , so rounded to an int, it is 0 .

so

```
a[i][j] = 10 - (0*(10)); // this yields 10, the value of "min"
```

Comment: @Kevin Esche just posted the answer to the display part , and the other answer by khelwood, tells you how to populate your array correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Where you have:

```
a[i][j] = min - (int)Math.random()*(max-min+1);
```

You actually mean:

```
a[i][j] = min + (int) (Math.random()*(max-min+1));
```

The first one casts `Math.random()` to an `int` (giving zero), then multiplies it by `(max-min+1)` (giving zero), then subtracts it from `min` (giving `min`).

The second one multiples `Math.random()` by an `int` (giving a random double in the range `[0,max-min+1)` ), then casts it to an `int` (giving a random int in the range `[0,max-min]` ), and then adds `min` (giving a random int in the range `[min,max]` ).

Comment: i guess you forgot to change the `-` to `+` in the correct calculation for the random.