# returns array's memory address and not the value

Tags: java

```
public int[][] updateGame(String[] inarr, int c) {

  int[][] userGuess = new int[10][4];

  for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {
      userGuess[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(inarr[j]);


      System.out.println("user guess in for loop: " + userGuess[i][j]);

      //return userGuess[i][j];
    }

  }

  //System.out.println("user guess in method:"+userGuess);

  return userGuess;

}
```

it only returns the address of array

Comment: its not the memory address its the object notation of array

Comment: Yes, it will return a reference to the array.  That's how it works in Java.  There is no way around this; that's how the language works.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648240/java-best-way-to-print-2d-array

Comment: It's the internal type of the array and the object's hashCode in hexi-decimal. Not the address. Not that it makes any more sense. It really should do what Arrays.toString does.

Comment: it doesn't return the value  even when i use Arrays.toString()

Comment: @EshaPatel try `Arrays.deepToString(arrayName)`