# Print elements from different size array

Tags: java

```
Integer [][] x = {{1,2,3},{4},{5,6}};
```

What is the best way to print the elements in stdout like this?

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

I have tried `Arrays.deepToString(x) but doesnt output what I desire`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Best way to print 2D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648240/java-best-way-to-print-2d-array) and you can use `int` instead of class `Integer`

Comment: Try this,     `System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.deepToString(x).replace("[","").replace(",","\n").replace("]","").replace(" ","")); `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Integer [][] x = {{1,2,3},{4},{5,6}};

        for(Integer[] y : x) {

            for(Integer i : y) {

                System.out.println(i);

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Output :

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Here it is : https://ideone.com/9ywcjz