# How to print an 2d array of Char (JAVA)

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to print out a gameBoard that has a "-" for each spot of the array: however every time I run this code I get this printed to the console:

> [[C@2a139a55.

Any suggestions?

```
public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        char realBoard[][] = new char[7][7];

        for (int i=0;i<7;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<7;j++){
                realBoard[i][j]='-';
            }
        }
        System.out.print((realBoard));
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(realBoard));` also, `for (int i = 0; i < realBoard.length; i++) {
   Arrays.fill(realBoard[i], '-');
  }`

Answer (score 2):

`realBoard` is an array, an object, so you can't just print it like that. You will need to iterate over the elements again

```
for(char[] y: realBoard) {
    for(char x: realBoard) {
        System.out.print(x);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: No; this isn't legal. You need to provide the type to `for-each` loops.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to use the array data of mark elsewhere, you would be better off just using print statements inside your loops.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
    //Print for each row
    System.out.print("-");
  }
  //Move to next line
  System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't print a 2D array like that. To print a 2D array in one line you can use:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(realBoard));
```

Or in multiple lines:

```
for(char[] x: realBoard)
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
```

Credits: [Java - Best way to print 2D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648240/java-best-way-to-print-2d-array)