# Is the Java method "Arrays.deepToString()" the most efficient way to print a 2D array?

Tags: java, c#, arrays

I've found similar questions like so:

> [Java - Best way to print 2D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648240/java-best-way-to-print-2d-array)

But they don't answer the question of- Is it more efficient?

I'm writing a basic little console game in C# that requires repeatedly clearing and writing to the console in order to refresh the game state. In searching for a more efficient way to do this than my current attempt, iterating through the array with a nested for loop and printing it that way, I found this in Java:

```
Arrays.deepToString(arrayName);
```

which does what I'm trying to achieve.

1. Is this more efficient than using nested loops in Java like so?:

   ```
   String[][] map = new String[10][10];

   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
       {
           map[i][j] = "=";
       }
   }

   boolean firstRun = true;

   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
       {
           if (j == 0 && firstRun == false)
           {
               System.out.print("\n");
           }

           System.out.print(map[i][j]);
           firstRun = false;
       }
   }
   ```
2. If it is more efficient, is there a C# library equivalent? I can't seem to find one or even someone asking about one anywhere.

Comment: How efficient do you need it to be and how efficient is it at the moment? You can't optimize performance without measuring it. Use a profiler.

Comment: Regardless of how efficient I need it to be, surely one or the other of these methods is theoretically more efficient, no?

Comment: I appreciate the quick answer, win-win haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at this from the wrong angle:

- your code is dealing with almost no data (10x10 is **nothing** in 2019)
- your code is doing console output

Rest assured: printing to stdout like this is **many** times more expensive than processing a close-to-nothing array in memory (see [here](https://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0603.html) for some example data).

Thus, the real answer is: you can safely **ignore** performance aspects here.

Instead invest your time into writing code that is easy to read, understand, and maintain. Coming from there, that *single* call to `Arrays.deepToString(arrayName);` is very much to be preferred over writing custom loops doing the same.

Keep in mind: in the java world, runtime performance doesn't come out of writing "clever" source code. It comes out of the JIT deciding "this code is used so often, I should translate it to machine code". If the JIT thinks "not worth optimising" then it is **not worth** optimising. If it is worth optimising, make *that* easy for the JIT. By writing simple and easy code.

Long story short: it is a nice exercise to *implement* that functionality, but now that you achieved that, throw it away and use the library call that works for you.

Comment: Although this isn't the code I was working with, I was just using it as an example, this definitely answers my question and helps a lot, thanks.