# Is there any algorithm to print out to console the array with squares?

Tags: java, algorithm

How can I visualize the array that I created in the code with brackets?
e.g for 3x3 array:

```
 [  ]    [  ]    [  ]   
 [  ]    [  ]    [  ]   
 [  ]    [  ]    [  ]
```

I tried a very simply code but the columns were below the others

```
for (int i=0;i<Columns;i++){
       for (int j=0;j<Rows;j++){
          System.out.println("[  ]");
       }
   System.out.println(" ");
}
```

Comment: Change the inner `println` to `print` and then print a `[`, the element(s), and then a `]`

Comment: please try System.out.print("[  ]");

Comment: @SofoGial I checked that question but it's totally different from the question that I have! Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Best way to print 2D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648240/java-best-way-to-print-2d-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Main{

 public static void main(String []args){

    int Columns = 3,Rows = 3;
    for (int i=0;i<Columns;i++){

           for (int j=0;j<Rows;j++){
              System.out.print("[  ]");
              System.out.format("\t");
           }
       System.out.println(" ");
    }

 }
```

}

This code will work. 
Do not use  `System.out.println()` instead use `System.out.print()`.

for reference click this link. https://www.onlinegdb.com/B1950yw2V

import java.util.Formatter in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Your biggest issue is that `System.out.println("[  ]");` prints each string out to a new line.

To get the desired effect, try `System.out.print("[  ]");`, which prints each column without adding a carriage return.

```
int Columns = 3;
int Rows = 3;

for (int i=0;i<Columns;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<Rows;j++){
        System.out.print("[  ]");
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
}
```

Output:

```
[  ][  ][  ]   
[  ][  ][  ]   
[  ][  ][  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```java
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int Columns = 3, Rows = 3;
        for (int i = 0; i < Columns; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Rows; j++) {
                sb.append("[  ]");
                if (j == Rows - 1) {
                    sb.append("\n");
                } else {
                    sb.append("\t");
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
```