# Brute force technique is returning some gibberish when applied on a 2D array

Tags: java, brute-force

I am trying to solve a 2D array question using brute force, but when I run the code in my IDE it returns something in gibberish that I am not able to decode.

Question: https://leetcode.com/problems/flipping-an-image/

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class flippingAnImage {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[][] arr = {{1,1,0},{1,0,1},{0,0,0}};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(flip(arr)));
    }

    public static int[][] flip(int[][] image){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < image.length ; i++){
            for(int j = image[i].length-1,k=0 ; j>=0 && k < image[i].length;j--,k++){
                image[i][k] = image[i][j];
            }
        }
        return image;
    }

}
```

This is what it returns:
[[I@5acf9800, [I@4617c264, [I@36baf30c]

Any help would be appreciated here

Comment: This is not garbage. I can't say why you are seeing this output, but this is a certain type of encoding https://stackoverflow.com/a/3442100/5744883

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/409795/5744883. You need to use `deepToString`. as you are printing nested array. Now look at your previous output. It is saying that, each element is an array. `[` is the encoding for array.

Comment: [Java - Best way to print 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648240/java-best-way-to-print-2d-array)

Answer (score 2):

`toString()` accepts one dimensional array as input argument and returns a string representation of it. It doesn't work for multi-dimensional arrays. Just replace `toString` with `deepToString()` for multi-dimensional array instead.

Like,

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayFlipper {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[][] arr = {{1,1,0},{1,0,1},{0,0,0}};
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(flip(arr)));
    }

    public static int[][] flip(int[][] image){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < image.length ; i++){
            for(int j = image[i].length-1,k=0 ; j>=0 && k < image[i].length;j--,k++){
                image[i][k] = image[i][j];
            }
        }
        return image;
    }

}
```

This would return output:

```
[[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0]]
```

If your code still doesn't give the intended output, think about why it's printing the current result.

Answer (score 1):

Because `arr` is a two dimension array. And what you print is the address of the rows about the `arr`. (Just as *user16320675* mentioned, the address of the rows is not correct here and it should be the hashcode of the rows) In java API(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) where you can find that there is no `toString(int[][] a)` but `toString(int[] a)`.
Your code can modify to get the value.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr[i]));
        }
```

But why is not the answer in *leetcode*. Your algorithm just flip but not invert. So you should think more about the algorithm you design.

Comment: there is no "address of the rows" being printed - it is just the hash code (as specified in the [`Object.toString` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#toString()): "... `getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())` ..." {the hash code may be *based* on the address, but it is not the address} {why call `Arrays.toString(arr[i]);` (first call) without ever using the result?}