# String representation of 2d array as tables with borders in java

Tags: java

Is there any library to get the `string` representation of any type of `2d` Java array as tables

with borders like the one in MySQL command line client?

I found related posts about pretty print `2d` array but they are working for only String type of arrays.

Comment: Could you add an example for those not familiar with MySQL command client?

Comment: Have a look at [Formatting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html)

Comment: What type of object 2D array contain?

Comment: it contains double values, but it would be great if it is generic.

Comment: I think you could use the code used in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383070/pretty-print-2d-array-in-java just change the parameters to `Object[][]`, because the method `getCellValue(value)` returns `value.toString()`.