# Java application subscribed to PostgreSQL/MySql

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql

I need to create a **Java agent that can be aware and execute its instruccions as soon as  any update for particular tables in a Mysql or Psql Database occurr**.
Everything needs to be done automaticaly.

I was wondering given Im a novice in Java you guys could give me any advice..

My options are:

1) Having a trigger that after a commit could awake my java application. (using Pg_notify and others)

2) or Having the java application subscribed to a particular ID in a database (not sure if this can be done given asynchronous updates are not possible and I might need to have my agent asking xx second to the dabatase for changes)

Thanks!

Comment: 2 database with same structure or not? Using JDBC or?

Comment: Nope structures might be different..but that should not be an issue. I think I could deal with that even if I need an app per DB. I should use JADE but if I have to go with JDBC that is fine.

Comment: What I want to suggest, if you using JDBC than you must make your own library to make it more easy for you. You can look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377602/creating-an-organized-java-library/10378415#10378415) for snapshot. Or maybe you can learn about [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) + [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) very useful I think for your problem.

Comment: Thank you! Ready to start reading and learning again then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a trigger that uses NOTIFY is a good way to do it in PostgreSQL. The important problem when using the JDBC driver is that there is no way to receive notifications asynchronously, you have to poll. This is usually fine as the NOTIFY/LISTEN mechanism is very light-weight: if you want to poll 10 (100?) times a second, then you can do so without causing performance problems. See http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/83/listennotify.html for more.

MySQL is a little less helpful; you'll need to have triggers INSERT rows into a monitoring table and repeatedly poll that table with SELECT * (and then DELETE). This will work, but you are more likely to end up in a latency/performance trade-off.

Comment: I was hoping I could get around pushing rather than pulling the data changes I need from the DB. That is my main aim..but after trying I thought the trigger idea was the best option. Thank you!

Comment: @user1373972: PostgreSQL's "notify/listen" is **very** lightweight "pull" mechanism. Don't be affraid using it.

Comment: A generalized trigger for notifying regarding table changes will be included in 9.2; if you don't mind compiling C code from source, it works fine with 9.0 and 9.1.  (We have been using it in production for almost a year.) http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/tcn.html http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=tree;f=contrib/tcn;h=aa9c5813223a3996e22cabbf064d7243fa474c6c;hb=HEAD Full disclosure: I wrote it.